# Totaling Up Amounts In A GUI

Tags: java, swing, button, user-interface, listener

My code below does everything I want it to, except it is missing one crucial function. I want it to take the value of each square and show it in the input box.  Then when the user presses total, it shows the final price plus 7 percent tax. Currently it is just an error, but before it was just putting the amounts in the total box without actually adding them up. How can I make it add them up properly? Thank you! Here are my 2 class files:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
public class PizzaOrder
{

    private JPanel phone;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Pizza Order");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel phone = new JPanel();
    phone.setBorder (BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());

    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
    tp.addTab ("Pizza Order", new PizzaGUI());

    frame.getContentPane().add(phone);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tp);
    frame.pack();
    frame.pack();frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class PizzaGUI extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel  resultLabel;


    private JButton button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttonclear;

    public  PizzaGUI()
    {
        // grid layout
        setLayout (new GridLayout (5, 3));

        // creates buttons  and label
        resultLabel = new JLabel (" ");
        button0 = new JButton ("Small: 10.00");
        button1 = new JButton ("Medium: 14.00");
        button2 = new JButton ("Large: 16.00");
        button3 = new JButton ("Soda: 2.00");
        button4 = new JButton ("Water: 1.50");
        button5 = new JButton ("Extra Cheese: 1.50");
        button6 = new JButton ("Pepperoni: 1.50");
        button7 = new JButton ("Mushroom: 1.50");
        button8 = new JButton ("Sausage: 1.50");
        button9 = new JButton ("Pepper Onion: 1.50");
        buttonclear = new JButton ("Total");

        //listeners for each button
        button0.addActionListener (new ButtonListener0());
        button1.addActionListener (new ButtonListener1());
        button2.addActionListener (new ButtonListener2());
        button3.addActionListener (new ButtonListener3());
        button4.addActionListener (new ButtonListener4());
        button5.addActionListener (new ButtonListener5());
        button6.addActionListener (new ButtonListener6());
        button7.addActionListener (new ButtonListener7());
        button8.addActionListener (new ButtonListener8());
        button9.addActionListener (new ButtonListener9());
        buttonclear.addActionListener(new ButtonListenerT());

        //adds all buttons and label
        add (resultLabel);
        add (button0);
        add (button1);
        add (button2);
        add (button3);
        add (button4);
        add (button5);
        add (button6);
        add (button7);
        add (button8);
        add (button9);
        add (buttonclear);


        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(720,360));
        setBackground (Color.white);
    }

    //code below is one listener per button
    private class ButtonListener0 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "10.00");
        }
    }


    private class ButtonListener1 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {



            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "14.00");
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener2 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "16.00");       
        }
    }


    private class ButtonListener3 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "2.00");        
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener4 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "1.50");         
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener5 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "1.50");        
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener6 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "1.50");         
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener7 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "1.50");         
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener8 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "1.50");        
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListener9 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {


            resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + "1.50");      
        }
    }

    private class ButtonListenerT implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {



            double total;

            resultLabel.setText ("Total plus tax:" + total = total *1.07);           
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I am programming since 3 years. I have never seen someone adding class name.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, I'm just trying to show an idea of what I want to achieve

Comment: What do you mean by total = ButtonListener0+ ButtonListener1+ ButtonListener2 + ...

Comment: I took that out, it was not making sense. I just want the values of each price to total up every time the button is pressed and then when the total button is pressed it shows the final total with the tax added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the OP's code is very vague and long to understand. So I'm going to throw a stone in dark.

In each button-listner's `actionPerformed` method except `ButtonListenerT`, change the code to

```
private class ButtonListener0 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        resultLabel.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(resultLabel.getText()) + 10.00));        
    }
}
```

for `ButtonListener2` `10.00` will be `16.00` and so on...

Now

```
private class ButtonListenerT implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        double total;
        total = Double.parseDouble(resultLabel.getText());
        resultLabel.setText ("Total plus tax: " + (total *1.07));           
    }
}
```

Comment: It says this: for the button listener 0:
"The method setText(String) in the type JLabel is not applicable for the arguments (double)"

Comment: Hmm it runs now. But when I hit any button it says all this in the console: (This is just a part of it can't post it all)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at PizzaGUI$ButtonListener2.actionPerformed(PizzaGUI.java:99)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown

Comment: `resultLabel = new JLabel ("0.00");` do this.

Comment: Ahhh, ok! Very interesting. Working now. Thank you for your help. If i make another tab, will that code just translate over?